# Updating the gem versions in the gemspec file automatically

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

My `*.gemspec` file holds content like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
    ...
    spec.add_development_dependency "guard", "~> 2.12.6"
    spec.add_development_dependency "unicorn"
    ....
end
```

Is there an automated way to change/add all the versions to latest one?
So at the end it would look like (assuming the versions stated here are the latest ones):

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
    ...
    spec.add_development_dependency "guard", "~> 2.13.0"
    spec.add_development_dependency "unicorn", "~> 5.0.1"
    ....
end
```

Comment: If you want to automatically update to the lastest version, why do you want to add a version number in the first place? I prefer to only add version numbers when I really have to because of a known incompatibility.

Comment: well, the idea here is, to have reproducible build process => fixed versions, but update these from time to time without a need to check and update all of them manually

Comment: Wouldn't do it automatically either (at least not all at once, to run tests after each one to see if nothing got broken), but used these bash one-liners to see the new versions of each gem: https://gist.github.com/smileart/9d1d17e9da8cba19f792304fd4b0e58d JIC someone comes here from Google.